# Bootstrap 3 horizontal aligning text and span in middle of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I am trying to align the `Back To Top` and the up carat in the middle of the div `container` but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using `Bootstrap 3`. How do I get this to align properly in the middle?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <a href="#" class="center-block">
        <p class="text-center" id="back-to-top">Back To Top</p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    </a>
    <p class="text-center" id="copyright">© 2014 LFDate. All rights reserved.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#back-to-top {
display: inline;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: By middle, do you mean horizontal middle or vertical center?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be wrapping your elements in a non-conventional way (i.e. a `<p>` inside an `<a>`)

I propose a different approach:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <a href="#" class="center-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Back To Top
    </a>
    <p class="text-center" id="copyright">
      © 2014 LFDate. All rights reserved.
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer{
  display: table;
}
#copyright {  
  display:table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**[See Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zswDo)**

Comment: If you need to space the two elements differently (i.e. like in the image), you can wrap them in `<div class="col-*">` according to your design (and remove the CSS I added)